# Session Timeout in angular 4 using ng-idle

Tags: angular, typescript, session

I have referred code from https://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng2-idle/ and modified it as , during onTimeoutWarning a modal popup will be opened and on timeout session will be cleared and navigated to Login page.

It is working fine. However, after navigating to Login page if user is logging in again, then timeout functionality is not working.

**Component**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { SessionService } from '../Service/session.service';
import { LoginService } from '../Service/login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Idle, DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES } from '@ng-idle/core';
import { Keepalive } from '@ng-idle/keepalive';
import { ModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    templateUrl: 'app/HTML/header.html'
})

export class HeaderComponent {


    //TodayDate: string;
    public EmployeeDetail: string = "";
    IsLoggedOut: boolean = true;

    idleState = 'Not started.';
    timedOut = false;
    lastPing?: Date = null;

    public flag: boolean = false;
    public sessionWarningTimer$ = new Subject();
    TodayDate: string;
    public CurrentDate: Date = new Date();
    @ViewChild('modal') modal: ModalComponent;


    constructor(
        private _loginservice: LoginService,
        private _sessionService: SessionService,
        private router: Router,
        public datePipe: DatePipe,
        private idle: Idle,
        private keepalive: Keepalive,) {

        _loginservice.getLoggedInName.subscribe(name => this.changeName(name));

        if (_sessionService.getItem("CurrentUser") != null) {
            this.TodayDate = this.datePipe.transform(Date.now(), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
            _loginservice.set(this._sessionService.getItem("CurrentUser").LastName + " " + this._sessionService.getItem("CurrentUser").FirstName + " | " + "Emp No - " + this._sessionService.getItem("CurrentUser").EmployeeNumber + " | " + "Dept - " + this._sessionService.getItem("CurrentUser").CurrentEmployee.DepartmentId + " | " + this._sessionService.getItem("CurrentUser").CurrentEmployee.FullTime + " | " + this._sessionService.getItem("CurrentUser").CurrentEmployee.Exempt  );

        }

        /**************************************************************************************************/
        this.reset();
        // sets an idle timeout of 5 seconds, for testing purposes.
        idle.setIdle(50);
        // sets a timeout period of 5 seconds. after 10 seconds of inactivity, the user will be considered timed out.
        idle.setTimeout(50);
        // sets the default interrupts, in this case, things like clicks, scrolls, touches to the document
        idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);

        idle.onIdleEnd.subscribe(() => this.idleState = 'No longer idle.');
        idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
            this.idleState = 'Timed out!';
            this.timedOut = true;
            //Logout

            this._loginservice.set("");
            this._sessionService.setItem("IsLoggedOut", true);
            this._sessionService.removeItem("CurrentUser");
            this.flag = false;
            this.timedOut = false;
            this.idleState = '';
            this.router.navigate(['Login']);
            this.modal.dismiss();
        });
        idle.onIdleStart.subscribe(() => this.idleState = 'You\'ve gone idle!');
        idle.onTimeoutWarning.subscribe((countdown) => {
            this.idleState = 'Your session is about to expire and you will logged out in ' + countdown + ' seconds!';
            if (!this.flag) {
                this.modal.open();
                this.flag = true;
            }
        });

        // sets the ping interval to 15 seconds
        keepalive.interval(15);

        keepalive.onPing.subscribe(() => this.lastPing = new Date());

        this.reset();
        /**************************************************************************************************/
    }
    private changeName(name: string): void {
        this.EmployeeDetail = name;
    }


    Logout() {
        this._loginservice.set("");
        this._sessionService.setItem("IsLoggedOut", this.IsLoggedOut);
        this._sessionService.removeItem("CurrentUser");
        this.router.navigate(['Login']);
    }

    reset() {
        this.idle.watch();
        this.idleState = 'Started.';
        this.timedOut = false;

    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<modal-header [show-close]="true">
    <h3 class="pageTitle">
        Session Timeout
    </h3>
</modal-header>
<modal-body>

    <section>
        <p><strong>{{idleState}}</strong></p>
        <!--<p *ngIf="lastPing"><small>Last keepalive ping <strong>{{lastPing | date:'h:mm a z'}} TimeAgo</strong></small></p>
        <button (click)="reset()" *ngIf="timedOut">Continue Session</button>-->
    </section>



</modal-body>
<modal-footer>
    <div *ngIf="!timedOut">
        <a class="btn btn-default" (click)="modal.dismiss()">Continue Session</a>
    </div>
</modal-footer>
```

Comment: did you try this.idle.onTimeout.unsubscribe();

Comment: @Hein Nguyen Any idea on where to incorporate this piece in the code above?

Comment: I tried this but not working

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `onTimeout` `subscribe` like this. It worked with me.

```
 this.idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
          //console.log('timeout')
          this.idleState = 'Timed out!';
          this.timedOut = true;
          swal.close();
          this.idle.stop();
          //prevent init multiple time
          this.idle.onTimeout.observers.length = 0;
          this.idle.onIdleStart.observers.length = 0;
          this.idle.onIdleEnd.observers.length = 0;

          this.signOut(this.getPath().substring(1));
});
```

Comment: What my observation is the Constructor of above Component is not called as it is part of App Component. Should I take another Component and use its tag in all other components?

Comment: I did not call it in AppComponent, only in Navbar component same as your Header component, navbar display in all my pages

Comment: Do you mean you have placed navbar selectors in html of all your htmls?

Comment: No, only in layout for all page

Comment: Hey Captainsac and @HienNguyen, Did you find a solution for this?